# Can fullproof update its full-text index without a complete re-index?

Tags: javascript, full-text-search

I'm evaluating the [fullproof](http://reyesr.github.io/fullproof/) javascript full text search engine, but I can't figure out if it can handle index updates.  From my reading of the api I don't see the mention of updating or deleting something from the index.

lunr.js for example can make [updates](http://lunrjs.com/docs/#update) to the index without a complete reindex.

I hope it can make index updates, because on my iPad, it took 10 minutes to create the index, which is prohibitive if it has to rebuild the index every time.  Compared to 40 seconds to create the lunrjs index. However the problem with lunr is that the complete index needs to be in memory, whereas in fullproof it puts the index in a local WebSQL db.

Comment: Around Mar'14 lunr has been at version 0.5.5. Since then they went to v2 and introduced breaking changes and completely redone the docs. Your "updates" link was intended to point at v0.x docs but now link redirects to v2 docs (Btw, in v2  I couldn't find feature to update index ... anyone?)  You can still find docs for the 0.x version on their github, or for convenience here is CDN link to [docs to last 0.x of lunr 0.7.2](https://cdn.rawgit.com/olivernn/lunr.js/v0.7.2/docs/index.html#update)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like fullproof can't update/delete items from it's index given the lack of comments on this [github issue](https://github.com/reyesr/fullproof/issues/21).

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak for fullproof, but there is nothing stopping you from snapshotting the lunr index into client side storage yourself.

Given the following index:

```
var idx = lunr(function () {
  this.ref('id')
  this.field('title')
})
```

You can dump it as JSON like this:

```
var dump = JSON.stringify(idx)
```

Now you can store that dump anywhere you like, I'm not overly familiar with WebSQL but storing it in localStorage might look like this:

```
localStorage.setItem('lunr_dump', dump)
```

To reload the index you do the following:

```
var idx = lunr.Index.load(dump)
```

Loading a dumped index back into lunr should be several orders of magnitude quicker than rebuilding it each time.

As you mention, lunr doesn't need to re-build the whole index each time, so lets say you update a document, and would like to keep the dumped version up to date:

```
idx.on('update', function (doc, index) {
  localStorage.setItem('lunr_dump', JSON.stringify(index))
})

idx.update(someDocument)
```

This will dump the entire index again, including any changes made when updating. It is worth benchmarking the dump, as there might be some overhead, especially with larger indexes.

If your data is relatively static you can actually pre-build an index on the server and send this to the client, saving the client the work of building the index on each page load, take a look at https://github.com/olivernn/lunr-index-builder

You can take this slightly further though, since the dumped index is just JSON, there is nothing stopping you indexing documents individually and then later merging the dumped indexes together, there is an [issue](https://github.com/olivernn/lunr.js/issues/29) here with some discussion and a link to a blog post about implementing it if your interested.

Comment: Thanks Oliver. I tried putting my lunr index into localStorage for my phonegap app on iOS before I wrote this, but it was too large, so it didn't save.  The thing I liked about fullproof was that the index structure was actually stored in the WebSQL database, so once the index is created, you never need to have the full index in memory.  So while you could store the lunr index into local storage of some description, you still need to bring the whole index into memory.  Although for my initial test of 1300 documents, my iPad didn't crash, I did like the idea of having it in a websql database.

Comment: Having said all that I preferred the results from lunr because it implements real stemming as opposed to fullproof which only implements metaphoning.  I like the idea of merging prebuilt indexes though, seems like a cool idea.  Although I managed to build my index in the background on my iPad (inside a WebWorker) for 1300 documents in 40 seconds, and most of those documents wouldn't change, so it's probably fine anyway.  As far as localStorage not allowing the index to be stored, I guess I could always store it in WebSQL or simply as a file since phonegap has access to writing/reading files.

Comment: Yeah, localStorage was just as an example. FWIW the very first versions of lunr were actually backed by IndexedDB in much the same way fullproof is built on top of WebSQL. It was so slow as to be broken, so I kept it all 'cached' in memory, soon after I decided that just keeping the whole thing in memory was better and discarded the IndexedDB cruft. Keeping the index in memory is what makes it faster, though its a tradeoff, perhaps some way of paging the memory from disk to memory (and back) would be a good idea, though I have a feeling that would be very complex.

Comment: Today I tried merging indexes as per the blog post, but I found the performance to be about 4 to 9 times slower. I think simply doing a deep merge of the token store is simply too inefficient. Probably need to work out a smarter index merge technique to make it worthwhile.